# Exiting a while loop when a global variable changes

Tags: python, while-loop, osc, neopixel

So, I've been working on an LED strip connected to my raspberry pi 4, and I've got TouchOSC working between the Pi and my phone. The current problem I'm having is when a toggle button I've pressed is turned off, the program it's designated to run continues running. I have a global variable that's supposed to determine if the "while" loop continues, but instead of setting the button state to zero and terminating the program, it continues to run until it's interrupted by a Ctrl+C in the terminal. I was wondering if anyone would happen to know why the program doesn't stop when the button state is change.

```
def twinkleBtn(path, tags, args, source):
    global twinkleState
    twinkleState = int(args[0])
    if twinkleState:
       turnOff(strip)
       while twinkleState:
            twinkleTest(strip, False, 10)
    if not twinkleState:
       turnOff(strip)
```

This is triggered when the twinkle button is pressed, but the program continues to run when I toggle it back to zero. Below is the code to the  function "twinkleTest"

```
def twinkleTest(strip, onlyOne, count, wait_ms=50):
    setPixels(Color(0, 0, 0))
    for i in range(count):
        strip.setPixelColor(randint(0,LED_COUNT), Color(170, 180, 30))
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/250.0)
        if (onlyOne):
           setPixels(Color(0,0,0))
    time.sleep(wait_ms/500.0)
```

I'm not sure if I'm just clueless or what exactly is being done wrong here. I'm pretty new to Python so it may not be the best. Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's nothing in shown code that matches your story about checking variables, attempting to quit etc

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - the code clearly sets and tests `twinkleState`

Comment: This makes no sense then because this value is constant? Or your explanation is confusing

Comment: Is the function really being called a second time? it could be that the infinite loop in the button keeps the framework from ever running the second button press. Perhaps the twinkling bit should be in a separate thread controlled by a synchronization object such as an event to turn it on and off.

Comment: @tdelaney It seems that it does get hung up in the loop and keeps the program from checking the state again, but I'm not entirely sure why that would be since the twinkleTest program would run once without the loop. I would think it should check `twinkleState` after each iteration of the program. I've been looking into using a separate thread for it, but I'm still new to the whole thing so I'm not quite sure about implementation. I was hoping the button press would act as the event to turn the program on and off, but obviously I'm not handling it right.

Comment: Yes, `twinkleBtn` has to return to keep the gui going so you need someplace else to do the twinkling. I mentioned a separate thread but your gui likely has a timer that can be set to `wait_ms/250.0` and run the (rewritten) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple threading solution. A thread waits on a `threading.Event`. `twinkleTest` is called whenever the event is set. The GUI sets the event, and twinkling will happen in the background until the button is pressed a second time to stop the twinkling.

```
import threading

def twinkleTest(strip, onlyOne, count, wait_ms=50):
    setPixels(Color(0, 0, 0))
    for i in range(count):
        strip.setPixelColor(randint(0,LED_COUNT), Color(170, 180, 30))
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/250.0)
        if (onlyOne):
        setPixels(Color(0,0,0))
    time.sleep(wait_ms/500.0)

def twinkler(twinkleEvent):
    """Call twinkleTest whenever the given twinkleEvent event is set
    and keeps calling until the event is cleared. Designed to be used in
    a separate thread."""
    while True:
        twinkleEvent.wait()
        twinkleTest(strip, False, 10)

def setup_twinkle_daemon_thread():
    """Creates a daemon thread to twinkle screen whenever an event is set.
    Returns event, threadhandle"""
    twinkleEvent = threading.Event()
    twinkleThread = threading.Thread(target=twinker, args=tuple(twinkleEvent))
    twinkleThread.daemon = True
    twinkleThread.start()
    return twinkleEvent, twinkleThread

# controls twinkler
twinkleEvent = twinkleThread = None

def twinkleBtn(path, tags, args, source):
    global twinkleEvent, twinkleThread
    if twinkleEvent is None:
        # start daemon thread on first use
        twinkleEvent, twinkleThread = setup_twinkle_daemon_thread()
    if twinkleEvent.is_set():
        twinkleEvent.clear()
    else:
        twinkleEvent.set()
```

Comment: Thank you! I revised my code with your suggestions, I am currently getting a `TypeError` from the `tuple(twinkleEvent)` I believe. It's displaying `'_Event' object is not iterable`. I'm not really familiar with tuple, but I've tried to look into it to see if there's anything I could change to take care of that error.

Comment: Hmm...., replace `tuple(twinkleEvent)`   with `(twinkleEvent,)` (note the comma) and it should work.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much! Fixed my problem, much appreciated!